# Loading data from a JSON file using jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm currently studying some AJAX and JSON online, can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? I'm trying to load items on my web page depending on which button is clicked and the category.

This is the JSON file content

```
[
item: [
    {
        title: "Proyecto 1",
        description: "Este proyecto fue realizado para la empresa X usando la tectnologia Y.",
        image: "img/proyecto1.jpg",
        category: "web"
    },
    {
        title: "Proyecto 2",
        description: "Este proyecto fue realizado para la empresa X usando los programas X y Y.",
        image: "img/proyecto2.jpg",
        category: "design"
    },
    {
        title: "Proyecto 3",
        description: "El siguiente video fue grabado para la empresa X usando la camara Y.",
        image: "img/proyecto3.jpg",
        category: "video"
    }
]
]
```

And this is the jQuery code I'm currently using.

```
$('.projectbutton').click(function(){
$('.projectbutton').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
var projectcategory = $(this).attr('project');
alert(projectcategory);

$.getJSON("test.json", function(response) {
    var projectHTML = '<div class="project">';

    $.each(response, function(i, project) {
        if (project.category == projectcategory) {
            projectHTML += '<img src=' + project.image + '/>';
            projectHTML += '<div class="projectdescription"><h1>' + project.title;
            projectHTML += '</h1><p>' + project.description + '</p>';
            projectHTML += '<img src=' + project.image + '/></div>';
        }
    }); //end each

    projectHTML += '</div>';
    $('#projectcontainer').html(projectHTML);
}); // end getJSON
}); // end click
```

I also tried with the $.ajax function!

Comment: In JSON, the attributes are usually also quoted.  In your data above, they aren't quoted.  Quotes are usually, also, double quotes.  Is your data source the raw JSON?

Comment: quick note: you don't want to add arbitrary attributes to html that aren't prefaced by 'data'. so you'll want to have a 'data-project' attribute instead of a 'project' attribute

Comment: run your json through [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) for validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. If you want to have properties (like `item`) you need to put in inside an JSON object literal:

```
{
    "item": [
        {
            "title": "Proyecto 1",
            "description": "Este proyecto fue realizado para la empresa X usando la tectnologia Y.",
            "image": "img/proyecto1.jpg",
            "category": "web"
        },
        .
        .
        .
    ]
}
```

Notice the curly braces (`{}`) instead of brackets (`[]`).

---

**UPDATE 1:** As [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) mentioned, you need to put your property names inside of quotes as well.  (I've updated the snippet to reflect this.)

**UPDATE 2:** You should use a [JSON Validator](https://www.google.com/search?q=json+validator) such as [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON and ensure that it is valid before trying to parse it in JavaScript.

Comment: more issues than that...lack of proper quotes make it invalid also

Comment: @MyStream `...` is your friend :)

Comment: Thank you guys for your fast answer and sorry for the dumb question (I'm self teaching myself and I don't have anyone to ask for help) I managed to solve it thanks to your answers.

Comment: @JesusAlbertoMendozaReveron, great! Glad to be of service.

Comment: @jsve can you visit my web page and take a look at the source code by any chance? It dosn't seem to work

http://mendozajesus.com/testjson

Comment: @JesusAlbertoMendozaReveron, it looks like the JSON file isn't being loaded. Please ask a new question if you need more assistance. It would be unconstructive to continue this conversation here in the comments since nobody would be able to find it later.

Answer (score 2):

Following from my comment, the formatting is off, but otherwise, you're on the right track.

```
// Converted to an Object with a single property, "item", which holds
// an array of objects
{
    "item": [
        {
            "title": "Proyecto 1",
            "description": "Este proyecto fue realizado para la empresa X usando la tectnologia Y.",
            "image": "img/proyecto1.jpg",
            "category": "web"
        },
        {
           "title": "Proyecto 2",
           "description": "Este proyecto fue realizado para la empresa X usando los programas X y Y.",
           "image": "img/proyecto2.jpg",
           "category": "design"
        },
        {
           "title": "Proyecto 3",
           "description": "El siguiente video fue grabado para la empresa X usando la camara Y.",
           "image": "img/proyecto3.jpg",
           "category": "video"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can check your JSON here: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON has a strange structure. It can almost work as described only missing one "{}" but the way to access it is a bit weird.

You can check out this fiddle sample:

[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xeo93vf6/1)

js:

```
var test = [{item: [{
    title: "Proyecto 1",
    description: "Este proyecto fue realizado para la empresa X usando la tectnologia Y.",
    image: "img/proyecto1.jpg",
    category: "web"
}, {
    title: "Proyecto 2",
    description: "Este proyecto fue realizado para la empresa X usando los programas X y Y.",
    image: "img/proyecto2.jpg",
    category: "design"
}, {
    title: "Proyecto 3",
    description: "El siguiente video fue grabado para la empresa X usando la camara Y.",
    image: "img/proyecto3.jpg",
    category: "video"
}]}];

var projectHTML = '<div class="project">';

    $.each(test[0].item, function(i, project) {
        if (true) {
            projectHTML += '<img src=' + project.image + '/>';
            projectHTML += '<div class="projectdescription"><h1>' + project.title;
            projectHTML += '</h1><p>' + project.description + '</p>';
            projectHTML += '<img src=' + project.image + '/></div>';
        }
    }); //end each

    projectHTML += '</div>';
    $('#projectcontainer').html(projectHTML);
```

Comment: That isn't a JSON string. That's a JavaScript object.